# how to add attribution in svg file?

Tags: xml, svg

i have an icon which i downloaded from svgrepo.com for an open source project and the icon( i.e svg) is licensed under https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/. so i have to add attribution.
i found there are many ways like adding  tag to the website of license etc.
but the thing is that i don't want any visual attribution. so how to add attribution in such a way that i only add attribution in svg file which will be not visual?

Comment: Use a <desc> tag. They are never rendered.

Answer (score 2):

`SVG` is `XML` so you can add an **XML Block Comment**:

```
<!-- 
    YOUR ATTRIBUTION HERE 
-->
```

Comment: will the comment in svg be considered as attribution in cc 4.0 license?

Comment: I am sure you can use something like `<!-- This work is licensed under a <a rel="license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/">Creative Commons Attribution 4.0 International License</a>. -->`